# Rails: Couldn't find Object without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an association between two models `product` and `order`. I want to copy some attributes from the `product` model to the `order` model and afterwards display in the view.

I'm also using `wicked` so changes to the routes may affect this, but the solutions I tried didn't work.

My OrdersController

```
before_action :set_product, only: [:create]

def create
@order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)
@order.business = @product.category
@order.save
end

private

def set_product
@product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

My Routes:

```
  resources :products do
    collection do
      get :ruby_on_rails, path: "ruby-on-rails"
    end
    resources :product_steps, path: "step", only: [:show, :update]
  end

  resources :orders do
    collection do
      get :requests
    end
    resources :order_steps, path: "step", only: [:show, :update]
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

To ger access to the product id inside your orders controller you need to nest the orders routes inside the products one. Be careful when nesting the product params is not `:id` but `:product_id`

You have an example in Wicked documentation about nested resources, you can [have a look here](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step)

Comment: When I insert the orders routes inside the products routes, I can't access for example `products/orders`, since I'm using `resources`.

Comment: you'd need to access `products/:product_id/orders` to do so. I you want a global orders endpoint, just nest the routes you need the product_id for inside products, using the `only: [:create]` option

Comment: I'm currently thinking of an easier way to handle this. Would it be possible to pass a hidden_field_tag with the product_id and associate it with the order ?